# Test if objects are equal and/or object has more keys but are still equal to the ones in common

Tags: javascript

I have three objects, object1: `{a: 1, b: 2}`; object2: `{a: 1, b: 3}`; object3: `{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}`, and would like to compare the last two to the first one, and only return them if they are equal (Doesn't matter if it has more values as long as the keys that it contains are equal to each other).

So, like, I'd like object3 to be returned.

Comment: You might want to rephrase your question. "equality" doesn't mean what you're saying. What you're looking for is called "unification": you want to find which objects can be unified with the first.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that word; now I know what to search for.

Comment: To be more precise, *unifying* two objects is not merely doing the comparison, it means creating an object that contains all the properties of both. But it is only possible if the properties with the same name have the same value in both objects (the objects are *unifiable*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check that each key in `a` is either absent from `b` or has the same value using `Array#all`:

```
function unifiable(a, b) {
    return Object.keys(a) . all(function(key) { return a[key] === b[key]; }); 
}
```

It is not necessary to explicitly check for the presence of `key` in `b`, since if `b` does not contain `key` then `b[key]` will be undefined, which will not be equal to any value of `key` in `a`.

The above will find values of `key` in the prototype chain of `b`, so if that is an issue you'll need to do an explict check for `b.hasOwnProperty(key)`.

If you want `NaN`s to be considered equal, you'd have to check separately for that.

This will simply check if the two objects are unifiable. To actually unify them as you want, a simple idea is

```
unifiable(a, b) && Object.assign(a, b)
```

Where `Object.assign` can be replaced by `$.extend`, `_.extend`, `Ember.merge`, or your other favorite object merger.

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer, because of the reference to underscore, which helped me do what I was trying to to achieve. (Using `_.isMatch`)

Comment: Good point about NaN and undefined. You can use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` instead of `keys()` to avoid inherited properties. Also, keep in mind this is shallow like all other answers we posted.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go (but please fix your question). This takes two arguments and returns whether they can be unified (i.e. whether the properties they have in common have the same value). It's only doing a shallow comparison though. Making it recursive for deep comparison is left as an exercise for the reader ;)

```
function unifiable(a, b){
  for(var prop in a) if(a.hasOwnProperty(prop)
      && b.hasOwnProperty(prop) && a[prop] !== b[prop])
    return false
  return true // will happen if the loop ended without returning
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function

Make A function that

- Checks for own properties
- checks that property of object a exists in object b
- finally matches the own properties of first object to the properties
  of  second object.

  ```
   function copareobjectkeys(a,b)
   {
       for(var k in a)
       {

        if(a.hasOwnProperty(k) && b.hasOwnProperty(k)  && b[k]!=a[k])
           return false;
       }
   return true
  }
  ```

Now having these three objects

```
a ={a: 1, b: 2};
b= {a: 1, b: 3}; 
c= {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
```

Comparing c with a and b with a

```
copareobjectkeys(c,a) //true
copareobjectkeys(b,a) //false
```

Comment: the `!!b[k]` condition in your code will prevent the detection of conflicts with any falsy value in `b`.

Comment: @Touffy no it will ensure that it is compairing if and only if b also has that key

Comment: i think after  b.hasOwnProperty(k) i dont need that

Comment: `!!b[k]` will be false if there is no k in b (but as you said it won't get there because the previous expression would catch that), but also if b[k] is undefined, false, null, 0, NaN or the empty string. So no, you don't need it and it's catching cases that it shouldn't.

Comment: i agrre with the point that it can also b NaN,0,empty string besides undefined. edited tahnks :)